# Raising an event from an observable object to it's container

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, observablecollection

I have an MVVM application, and have data bound a grid to an observable collection.  The collection is sorted like so:

```
 public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyData 
 { 
     get 
     {
        return _myData;
     }
     set 
     {
        _myData = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>(value.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateParam));
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyData);
     }
 }
```

This works fine when I add an entry, however, it is possible that the date `MyObject.DateParam` will change.  Despite both the object and the collection raising a `NotifyPropertyChanged` as shown, it doesn't update.  My workaround is as follows:

```
SelectedDataEntry.DateParam = DateTime.Now;
MyData = MyData;
```

Please somebody tell me there's a slicker way to do this.

Comment: Do you update observableCollection after updating dateParam?

Comment: I don't really understand that question, as you can see, I do; but the question is as to how I can achieve this without.

Comment: Wait a second, I'm working on it ;)

Comment: @pm_2 In debug mode, after changing DateParam, is value in ObservableCollection is also changing?

Comment: Yes.  The problem is that the collection is not being notified it has changed (hence why MyData = MyData works)

Comment: Did you try to raisepropertychanged after setting new datetime?

Comment: Effectively, that's what I'm doing. I don't think it's very neat though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not so much about raising changed events of an `ObservableCollection`, but simply on how to provide an ordered observable collection, which responds to `INotifyPropertyChanged` of the ObservableCollections items.

I recommend using a custom collection, which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`. The functionality you're asking for is not supported by `ObservableCollection`, nor by WPF's `CollectionViewSource` which is WPF's in-house solution for sorting and filtering collections.

Here is my implementation, I haven't tested it but you should get it to work as intended:

```
/// <summary>
/// ObservableCollection, supporting sorting of items
/// which automatically refreshes when items notify property changes.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Item type</typeparam>
public sealed class SortableObservableCollection<T> : INotifyCollectionChanged, ICollection<T>
{
    private readonly IComparer<T> _comparer;

    private readonly List<T> _innerItems; 

    public SortableObservableCollection(IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        _comparer = comparer;
        _innerItems = new List<T>();
    }

    public SortableObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        _comparer = comparer;
        _innerItems = new List<T>(collection);
    }

    private void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Sort();
    }

    public void Sort()
    {
        _innerItems.Sort(_comparer);
    }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    private void RaiseAdd(T newItem)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null) CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, newItem));
    }

    private void RaiseRemoved(T oldItem)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null) CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, oldItem));
    }

    private void RaiseReset()
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null) CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _innerItems.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        // Subscribe to items change notification
        var inpc = item as INotifyPropertyChanged;
        if (inpc != null) inpc.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
        _innerItems.Add(item);
        Sort();
        RaiseAdd(item);
        RaiseReset();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        foreach (var innerItem in _innerItems)
        {
            var inpc = innerItem as INotifyPropertyChanged;
            if (inpc != null) inpc.PropertyChanged -= Item_PropertyChanged;
        }
        _innerItems.Clear();
        RaiseReset();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return _innerItems.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _innerItems.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        // Unsubscribe from item's change notification
        var inpc = item as INotifyPropertyChanged;
        if (inpc != null) inpc.PropertyChanged -= Item_PropertyChanged;
        var removed = _innerItems.Remove(item);
        if (!removed) return false;

        Sort();
        RaiseRemoved(item);
        RaiseReset();

        return true;
    }

    public int Count { get { return _innerItems.Count; }}

    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }
}
```

It basically wraps a `List<T>` and raises the same events as an `ObservableCollection<T>` on the according operations (`Add(T)`, `Remove(T)`, `Clear()`). Additionally it performs a `Sort()` ing operation when items are added or removed and subscribes to the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event of each items to perform a sort when an item has changed.Note, that a collection `Reset` is raised on every sort. This is not a very performant solution, but you can refine it according to your needs by implementing a custom sorting operation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to create observable collection like :

```
private ObservableCollection<MyObject> _myData = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyData
{
     get{ return _myData;}
}
```

And then for example

```
MyData[0].DateParam = DateTime.Now;
MyData.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateParam);
```